# Sudo command not found (error in Jenkins execute shell)

Tags: linux, unix, jenkins, scripting, sudo

When I'm executing a unix command in jenkins job (through execute shell) with sudo, it throws error like this:

```
..../bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7505852448142784880.sh
+ sudo whoami 
/tmp/hudson7505852448142784880.sh: line 2: sudo: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What linux distro are you using. Not all distros have sudo installed by default

Comment: Be sure that `sudo` is installed, and that your `PATH` contains its directory.

Comment: its oracle linux... in terminal sudo is working fine.... only in jenkins buil(execute shell its not working) @Leon Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: How do you run Jenkins? Do you start it manually or is it installed as a daemon? Make sure sudo works for the user that runs the Jenkins process.

Comment: @MarcelPfeiffer  ..i dont start it manually...it runs on localhost ...... i have modified such that jenkins is run under different user with sudo permissions

Answer (score -3):

Jenkins runs with 'jenkins` user. Just cause it works in terminal with your logged in user, doesn't mean that it's configured to work with 'jenkins' user.

From your terminal, do:
`sudo su jenkins`
and *then* try running `sudo` from jenkins's user

Comment: i have modified jenkins to run under different user with sudo permissions ... simple whoami in execute shell gives the username as output not s jenkins...@Slav